# Connecting to Postgres through Go uses the wrong connection string

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to set up a local version of my Postgres db to do some testing. I have 2 sets of connection variables in my `.env`, one for the local database, and one for remote. When printing the connection string immediately before connecting, everything appears correct with the local variables. But when connecting using `sql.Open()`, it attempts to connect to the remote, even though the connection string doesn't have that info in it.

In trying to isolate the issue, I removed the remote postgres variables from the `.env`, instead of it erroring out because it doesn't have the remote variables that it was previously trying to connect to, it correctly connects to the local database. Also, it isn't an issue with `IS_LOCAL`, because when I change that to just `if true` is has the same issue.

I think the issue is something to do with the `DB_NAME` variable as the error is that the production database name doesn't exist on local, so the rest of the connection variables seem to be working properly.

This is the whole postgres.go file, I call `godotenv.Load()` without errors in main before calling `GetPostgresInstance`.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "github.com/charmbracelet/log"
)

type postgresSingleton struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

var postgresInstance *postgresSingleton
var postgresOnce sync.Once

func GetPostgresInstance() *sql.DB {
    postgresOnce.Do(func() {
        postgresInstance = &postgresSingleton{}

        var (
            DB_HOST    = os.Getenv("PGHOST")
            DB_PORT    = os.Getenv("PGPORT")
            DB_USER    = os.Getenv("PGUSER")
            DB_PASS    = os.Getenv("PGPASSWORD")
            DB_NAME    = os.Getenv("PGDATABASE")
            DB_SSLMODE = os.Getenv("SSLMODE")
        )

        if os.Getenv("IS_LOCAL") == "true" {
            DB_HOST = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGHOST")
            DB_PORT = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGPORT")
            DB_USER = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGUSER")
            DB_PASS = ""
            DB_NAME = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGDATABASE")
            DB_SSLMODE = os.Getenv("LOCAL_SSLMODE")
        }

        postgresqlDbInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s "+
            "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
            DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_SSLMODE)

        fmt.Println(postgresqlDbInfo)

        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", postgresqlDbInfo)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        postgresInstance.db = db
    })

    return postgresInstance.db
}
```

I've been hitting my head against my desk on this for a while, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to share the error with us? Also please confirm that the error is generated by the `Open`; generally this does not actually establish a network connection with the database (that happens when a request is made). I can't seen an issue with the code included in your question so suspect the issue is elsewhere. It may  also be useful to know which driver you are using (I'm guessing `github.com/lib/pq` but you may want to consider `github.com/jackc/pgx/stdlib`?).

Comment: What does this have to do with .env files? You are using `os.Getenv()` which returns regular OS environment variables. Unless you have other code that reads a .env file and uses `os.Setenv()` to copy them into the OS environment var pool I don't see the relevance of saying "my .env". And if you are copying .env file content into the OS environment heap you should show us that code as well.

Comment: @KurtisRader the question does state "I call `godotenv.Load()`" (which I assume is `github.com/joho/godotenv`; this will read in the `.env` file, and call `os.Setenv`, as per your comment). However if `fmt.Println(postgresqlDbInfo)` prints out the expected connection string then this is all irrelevant (unless, as I suspect, its referred to elsewhere).

Comment: @Brits Here's the error message: `2023/07/05 13:05:33 ERRO pq: database "ferrywatch_db" does not exist`, "ferrywatch_db` being the name of the production db, the local one is just named "postgres"

Comment: @Brits, You write `which I assume is github.com/joho/godotenv`. JHC! We shouldn't have to guess how you have initialized the environment and I don't understand why you say "I assume". If you don't know how you initialized the environment vars for the process how the heck are we supposed to know how you did so? In light of everything you've written so far (and three decades as a Unix support engineer) I am confident you are not accurately reporting all relevant facts.

Comment: One thing to note is that `lib/pq` does process environment variables itself (including [`PGDATABASE`](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go#L2035)); this may explain why removing the `PGDATABASE` environmental variable makes a difference (the library defaults to `localhost`). However the connection string *should* override this (and what you have posted *looks* correct).

Comment: @KurtisRader Brits is not OP, using "I assume" when trying to provide context on behalf of someone else is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order

```
postgresInstance = &postgresSingleton{}

    var (
        DB_HOST = os.Getenv("PGHOST")
        DB_PORT = os.Getenv("PGPORT")
        DB_USER = os.Getenv("PGUSER")
        DB_PASS = os.Getenv("PGPASSWORD")
        DB_NAME = os.Getenv("PGDATABASE")
    )

    if os.Getenv("IS_LOCAL") == "true" {
        DB_HOST = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGHOST")
        DB_PORT = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGPORT")
        DB_USER = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGUSER")
        DB_PASS = ""
        DB_NAME = os.Getenv("LOCAL_PGDATABASE")
    }

    postgresqlDbInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require",
        DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
```

Comment: I tried that, adding an extra variable to set the sslmode, and am hitting the same connection error. The string doesn't appear to be the issue because it prints correctly right before running the Open command.

I've updated the code in the post to reflect the changes.